# The add to cart button not showing on home page of magento

Tags: magento

Add to cart button not showing on Home page's Products.
On category/search page it is showing but not on home page.
I am using magento CE1.9

Comment: What are you showing  in the home page? static content? related,newest,special products modules? We need more info

Comment: Static content & New products module. you may check my site www.sevaaa.com

Answer (score 0):

The add to cart button link is hidden.

In your css (madisonisland.css line 182 you have)

```
.cms-index-index .products-grid .ratings, .cms-index-index .products-grid .actions, .cms-index-noroute .products-grid .ratings, .cms-index-noroute .products-grid .actions {
    display: none;
}
```

If you want to show the add to cart links change `display:none` to `display:block`

Comment: I modified the css file, It worked. But 'Add to Cart' button is overlapping with every product.